# Supervisor as non-root user

Tags: python, debian, supervisord

I have been trying to get supervisor running as a non root user but came against problems time after time. The more I have read into it the more it looks like supervisor is meant to be run as root.

I even read somewhere that it is only possible to run subprocesses as their own users under supervisor if supervisor is running as root.

MY question is, is it possible to get supervisor to run as non-root and still start subprocesses as non-root users also. Secondly, other then creating the user and setting the user in the supervisor.conf, is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Presumably you meant `supervisord` (from http://supervisord.org)?

Comment: Yes, thats right, sorry!

Comment: To be able to run processes as *other* users than itself, `supervisord` *must* run as root. That's a restriction of UNIX processes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be able to run any subprocess as a *different* user from what `supervisord` is running as, you *must* run `supervisord` as root.

When you run `supervisord` as a user other than root, it *cannot* run subprocesses under another user. This is a UNIX process security restriction.